# C++ style for header files

Tags: c++, coding-style, header, header-files

Suppose I have the following files:

1. main.cpp
2. routine.cpp
3. routine.h

Suppose further that main.cpp calls a function `routine()` that is defined in routine.cpp, but routine.cpp also contains functions that are **only** used by the `routine()` function.  In other words, routine.cpp contains both functions that are only called from within routine.cpp and functions that are called from other source files.

Obviously main.cpp will contain `#include "routine.h"`.  But should routine.h contain prototypes of **all** functions that are defined in routine.cpp (style A), or should routine.h **only** contain prototypes of functions that are called from other source files (style B)?

I've always written code after style A, but recently I've wondered if style B makes more sense stylistically.  (If style B is used, then the prototypes of the functions that are used only inside routine.cpp could be at the top of routine.cpp, or the definitions could simply precede their usage.)

Comment: One question per post. Also, the second question is likely to be closed as "not constructive" anyway.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: sorry, message received.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, the header only contains methods of the public interface (if those are free functions). You can declare the auxiliary methods used in `routine.cpp` in an anonymous namespace.

```
//routine.h

void foo();
void goo();

//routine.cpp

namespace
{
   void fooHelper() {}
   void gooHelper() {}
}

void foo()
{
   fooHelper();
}
void goo()
{
   gooHelper();
}
```

Such functions were previously declared `static`, which gave them internal linkage, but the general style now is to use anonymous namespaces.

Comment: So what is the effect of placing `fooHelper(){}` and `gooHelper(){}` in the "anonymous namespace" inside routine.cpp?

Comment: @synaptik you can't use the functions outside of that translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

Google's style guide is very comprehensive.  It provides pros/cons and justification for their choices.
http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml

Comment: Google style guide is for legacy Google projects, and is *not* a good modern C++ style guide.

Comment: Perhaps most relevant to your OP: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#The__define_Guard

Comment: @CatPlusPlus thanks for a relatively unhelpful comment... In your opinion their guide is not a good "modern" C++ guide.  However it is actually quite good, and at least they took the time to create one as comprehensive as it is.  Perhaps by providing an alternative to it you might actually be contributing positively.  As a new member to Stack, and a very commercially experienced programmer I don't exactly get the feeling that opinions are welcomed.

Comment: It's not good. It's not just my opinion. You can come to Lounge and we can play "enumerate reasons why GCSG sucks", again. This is not the place.

Comment: @Scottymac: Feel free to come to the C++ chat, and we can discuss this in great depth. However, the Google style guide *is* an abomination.

Answer (score 0):

routine.h should not contain declarations of those functions that are not intended to be used outside of the routine.cpp (style B).